# Android application allowing users to download online content

Tags: java, android, mysql, eclipse, sqlite

I am creating an android application using the 2.2 API. I have created the layout of the app (Design interface) and now i need to populate my application with data.

For example, my application shall allow users of my uni to login and then find lecture (PDFS and POWERPOINT DOCUEMENTS) and be able to view them.

Now i am unsure whether to do this using a database where the files have been pre saved so when the user requires the files it is accessed from the database

OR

whether to have some sort of coding that directly links, say a button 'Lecture 3' to the actual web link of Lecture 3?

We have a Blackboard system which holds/displays all our lecture and labratory material, so i could have a link to the material held in the website?

I've heard of JSON, JQUERY but completely unsure on what they are lol.

I was going to use SQLite as my database, however, refering back to what i said before, i am unsure whether that can hold files (DOC, PPt etc)

Look forward to all your help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Your question is quite open. Not sure you will get a precise answer. However, welcome to SO

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your Application as **off line**(without internet user can access files) then  Take files from server and store those files in Application memory and store that path in local data base.when you want to show those files to user take the path from data base,go to the path location and show files to user.

else download the files directly from server and show those files to user at that time only.